# Do I get a tax credit for my dependent’s short term capital loss?

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax, capital-loss, dependents

My father is not working and is my dependent. I have him $5,000 cash as a gift in 2020. He “invested” it in stock market (bought an option for something), and lost it all.

If he had any income, then he would have got the tax credit. Unfortunately, he doesn’t have any income. Can I get a tax credit for that $5,000 loss?

Comment: I doubt it, for the same reason you wouldn't owe any tax if he had recognized a capital gain.

Comment: Will he be able to carry over that loss to the next year?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that this is the U.S. then if your name is not on the brokerage account then you can neither be taxed nor can you deduct the loss.  Your father's social security number is what the broker uses for reporting the transactions to the IRS.

Per your comment, he will be able to carry over that loss to the next year.  [Fairmark.com](https://fairmark.com/investment-taxation/capital-gain/capital-losses/capital-loss-with-little-or-no-income/) provides an explanation and an example:

> Your capital loss carryover is reduced by the amount of capital loss that was actually used to reduce your taxable income, not by the amount of capital loss deduction shown on your tax return. In figuring this amount, you’re allowed to use all other deductions before using the capital loss deduction. This rule is reflected in a Capital Loss Carryover Worksheet that appears in the instructions for Schedule D and also in IRS Publication 550, Investment Income and Expenses.